# Postgresql "could not connect to server: No such file or directory" homebrew, OS X (10.10.3 Yosemite)

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have Postgresql installed via Homebrew on OS X 10.10.3. and I am getting the following error when I try to run psql from the command line.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Postgresql is starting up and works normally. I do not see any errors in the server log. The only way I can get psql to connect to the server is when I pass the -h localhost flag

```
psql -h localhost
```

Even though connecting to localhost rather than via the socket does work,  I would love to get to the bottom of why the socket is not being created. I have tried checking for a rogue postmaster.pid file and nothing is there when the server is shut down.

Could anyone shed some light on what might be blocking socket connections here?

Comment: That used to happen when using Apple's `/usr/bin/psql` client against non-Apple postgres server. Since OSX 10.10 or 10.9 Apple no longer provides `/usr/bin/psql` so it should no longer happen in general. As it does for you I guess you should check that you're launching the psql coming with homebrew and not another one.

Comment: This is a real FAQ, have you read the numerous similar questions already posted here?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried the solutions proposed in almost every other similar question to this one all without fixing the issue